# In React 16.4.0, how is using the new context syntax better than just exporting an object literal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React 16.4.0, why use the in-built Context component, when you can accomplish the same thing using something like an object literal you import to whoever that needs it?

In Facebook's example (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples), the theme-context.js file can essential pass the object literal directly rather than use ThemeContext. The app.js code can read theme-context exported object literal and pass it's value as props to them-button.js. Using context component seems unnecessary. Here is the code taken from [Facebook's tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples):

theme-context.js

```
export const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: '#000000',
    background: '#eeeeee',
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: '#ffffff',
    background: '#222222',
  },
};

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext(
  themes.dark // default value
);
```

themed-button.js

```
import {ThemeContext} from './theme-context';

function ThemedButton(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {theme => (
        <button
          {...props}
          style={{backgroundColor: theme.background}}
        />
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  );
}

export default ThemedButton;
```

app.js

```
import {ThemeContext, themes} from './theme-context';
import ThemedButton from './themed-button';

// An intermediate component that uses the ThemedButton
function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <ThemedButton onClick={props.changeTheme}>
      Change Theme
    </ThemedButton>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      theme: themes.light,
    };

    this.toggleTheme = () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        theme:
          state.theme === themes.dark
            ? themes.light
            : themes.dark,
      }));
    };
  }

  render() {
    // The ThemedButton button inside the ThemeProvider
    // uses the theme from state while the one outside uses
    // the default dark theme
    return (
      <Page>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.theme}>
          <Toolbar changeTheme={this.toggleTheme} />
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
        <Section>
          <ThemedButton />
        </Section>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.root);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you missed is that the change in context will ineffect change the value received at Consumer there by initiating a rerender which cannot be achieved by importing the value.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it. The answer is in the doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#provider.